# Front end form validation

Tags: javascript

I'm confused right now. It seems I'm missing something right here. Trying to submit the form, the code for the email field was running through the username. For instance, if I click on the submit button while the input for username and email were empty, the code for email, "email cannot be blank" would run through the username field. I need your response on this.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const password = document.getElementById("password");
const confirmpass = document.getElementById("re-password");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  Checkvalue();
})

function Checkvalue(){
  const userval= username.value.trim();
  const emailval =  email.value.trim();
  const passwordval= password.value.trim();
  const confirmpassval = confirmpass.value.trim();
  
  if (userval == '') {
    setErrorFor(username, 'username cannot be blank');
  }else{
    setSuccessFor(username);
  }
  
  if (emailval=='') {
    setErrorFor(email, 'enter your mail');
  }else if (!isEmail(emailval)) {
    setErrorFor(emailval, "email is not valid");
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(email);
  }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message){
  const formContol = input.parentElement;
  const small = document.querySelector('small');
  
  small.innerText = message;
  formContol.className = 'form-contol error'
}

function setSuccessFor(input){
  const formContol = input.parentElement;
  formContol.className = 'form-contol success'
}

function isEmail(email){
  const re =  /\S+@\S+\. \S+/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: HTML has really good form validation built-in without the need for JS. Have you looked into that?